# Apache Rewrite Dynamic Subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can i rewrite the urls in .htaccess like below example and remove a dynamic part from url ?

`https://example.com/abc/123/efg`
 =>
`https://example.com/abc/efg`

while `123` is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use RedirectMatch directive like this:

`RedirectMatch 301 /abc/([0-9]+)/(.*) /abc/$2`